# What is the user / password to login the live dvd system?

Tags: live-usb

I have the bootable dvd from the Aug 2015 copy of Linux Format Mag but cannot proceed past the login .. what is the default user / password?

Answer (score 0):

The default username is "ubuntu", and the password is blank on an Ubuntu LiveCD/DVD.

If it doesn't work, you can add a new user like this:

Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and run this command:

```
adduser username
```